# I'm trying to return data from a website using jsoup, but when I execute get() method an exception appears

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm new on android and I'm trying to return data from a website using jsoup, but when I execute get() method an exception appears. Here is my code:

```
public void Iqama (View view) throws IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();

}
```

Here is my logcat

```
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3735)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17948)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3730)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     ... 11 more
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     at rasha.example.masjed.Second.Iqama(Second.java:35)
06-07 12:59:38.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2281):     ... 14 more
06-07 12:59:51.831: I/Process(2281): Sending signal. PID: 2281 SIG: 9
06-07 12:59:52.151: D/libEGL(3235): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-07 12:59:52.151: D/libEGL(3235): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-07 12:59:52.151: D/libEGL(3235): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3544079)
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): Local Branch: adreno_20130328
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): Remote Branch: 
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): Local Patches: 
06-07 12:59:52.161: I/Adreno200-EGL(3235): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-07 12:59:52.201: D/OpenGLRenderer(3235): Enabling debug mode 0
06-07 13:00:22.140: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3235): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

And Here is my Mainfest file

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

and used this permission before the application tag in the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I am using JSOUP-1.7.2.jar in libs folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672644/error-in-http-connectionandroid-os-networkonmainthreadexception/16672694#16672694. check this link

Answer (score 1):

Your error which cause the crash is NetworkOnMainThreadException. You call network function on main Ui thread. You should use AsyncTask. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();` takes a lot of time and is not allowed to take place in the UI thread.

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Have a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to solve your problem.

Something like:

```
private class JsoupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
   protected Document doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
       Document doc;
       doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
       return doc;
   }


   protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
       // do something with doc
   }
}
```

To run it:

```
new JsoupTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsyncTask` ([API Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) and remove the `android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`.